# What HTTP cache headers should nsgw.json be served with?

Tags: angular, azure, angular11, angular-service-worker

I'm deploying an Angular 11 app to an Azure AppService. The app uses a Service Worker. My users are experiencing caching issues. I've fixed a lot of these by setting the cache control header on the index.html to `no-cahce`, but they're still experiencing issues. I think it's down to the App not updating, so I'm wondering what cache-control headers the nsgw.json and manifest.webmanifest need to be served with? I can't find any documentation about *serving* and angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any documentation either while having a similar issue, so I checked what [angular.io](https://angular.io/) (also an Angular app itself) uses as `cache-control`:

- The HTML page has `no-cache`
- `ngsw.json` and `pwa-manifest.json` have `max-age=3600`
- `ngsw-worker.js` has `max-age=86400`

I'm no sure why `ngsw.json` is allowed to be cached, but otherwise these values seem reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a definitive answer, but a hint that might help you configure the caching behaviour of your app with service workers. in `ngsw-config.json` there is a property to control how to update the cached ressources. I do not see your file details but there should be `"updateMode": "prefetch"`. This is where you control the behaviour of your cached ressources in your app. [Read on Angular Docs the values that can be passed to the `updatedMode`](https://%20https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#updatemode). You can try to set the `updateMode` to `lazy`.

According to documentation, `lazy`:

> Tells the service worker to not cache those resources. Instead, it
> treats them as unrequested and waits until they're requested again
> before updating them. An updateMode of lazy is only valid if the
> installMode is also lazy.